# Convert data to table and send it as email in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV report which i want to send as email message in a pretty table.

My CSV file:

```
Blah1|blah2|blah3|blah4
Abc |def  |ghi  |ijk
```

My code

```
$file= import-csv c:\file.csv | convertto-html
Send-emailmessage -smtpserver “blah” -body $([string]$($file)) -subject “blah”
```

Comment: So, what's the question / issue?

Comment: @Santiago sqarzon the output in the email is just raw data without tables with rows and columns.

Comment: Maybe you mean that the borders of the table are not visible?

Comment: @santiago sqarzon yup. No borders. Just datas.

Comment: Sounds like your table needs some Css

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment, the issue is probably because your table's border style is not visible which is usually set on your CSS.

A few points to note, there is no such cmdlet as `Send-EmailMessage`, you're probably referring to [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1). In addition, you should use the `-BodyAsHTML` switch or the mail will be Plain Text (not sure if this is mandatory).

If you want to learn more about how to make your table prettier, I would recommend [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css) website which is very friendly.

Last point to note, if you're planning to use [**zebra striped tables**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_zebra.asp), you should know that many mail clients are **not** compatible with `nth-child(even)` and as workaround, you should loop on even or odd rows to replace your `<td>` for a CSS class.

Give this a try:

```
$css = @'
<style>
* {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
'@

[string]$html = Import-Csv c:\file.csv | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $css
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer blah -Body $html -Subject blah -BodyAsHTML
```

Comment: i tried it but its still not giving me the datas in table, no rows and columns.

Comment: @jacktheripper are you using the `-BodyAsHTML` switch as in my answer?

Comment: Sqarzon yes i did add it.